# How do we visualise multiplication and division (reciprocal multiplication) in physical equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, conservative-field

All formulas have terms generally multiplied or divided to represent another physical quantity. Like $F=ma$, $I=Q/t$, $W=F.s$ etc.
Technically this is so because of ratios and proportionalities, the constants are generally hidden in the units, but still if we were to look at quantities like energy, force individually, how do we visualise say force and displacement in energy, say potential energy.

I have had this doubt since ages but it surfaced again when I read about torque. τ=Fxr, how to visualise F and r being multiplied? And the result coming perpendicular to them? Has it got something to do with the idea of ease of doing the thing in terms of centripetal force?

Am 18 studying in high school(12th grade)

Answer (score 0):

Some quantities have useful geometric interpretations.

- Work done is equal to the area under the force-vs-position curve.
- Work done is equal to the area under a thermodynamic process on pressure-vs-volume PV diagram.
- Torque is equal to the signed-magnitude of the cross-product of the momentArm and the force, which is visualized as the area of the parallelogram formed by the momentArm vector and the force vector.
- The change in velocity is equal to the area under acceleration-vs-time graph.
- The change in position is equal to the area under velocity-vs-time graph.

While the above may suggest multiplication (especially when both quantities are constant), one could turn things around and interpret them as a division problem.

- e.g., Given a fixed quantity of torque, if you make the width of the base of the parallelogram small, then the height of the parallelogram must be large.

Comment: Yes, that's helpful